# TypeError: 'numpy.complex128' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

Here is the object I am using in my code:

```
def AF(self, cur, theta):
    AF_out = 1
    self.cur = np.array(cur)

    for m in list(range(int(RING_NUM))):
        for i in list(range(RING_ELEMENT_NUM[m], int(np.sum(np.fromiter((RING_ELEMENT_NUM[0:m]), float))))):
            AF_out = 1 + np.sum(np.fromiter((np.sum(np.fromiter((self.cur[i] * exp(1j * K * (m * WAVELENGTH / 2) *
                                                                                   sin(theta) * cos(
                PHI - 2 * pi * (i - 1) / RING_ELEMENT_NUM[m]))), float))), int))
    return AF_out
```

When I run my code, the following error appears:

```
File "D:\download\metaheuristic algorithm\exercise_files\14. Genetic Algorithms Implementation - Simple Example __ 5.1 GeneticAlgorithmElitism.py", line 122, in AF
    AF_out = 1 + np.sum(np.fromiter((np.sum(np.fromiter((self.cur[i] * exp(1j * K * (m * WAVELENGTH / 2) *
TypeError: 'numpy.complex128' object is not iterable
```

I've found a lot of similar topic for this error, but I could not solve this error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I must modify my code like this:

```
def AF(self, cur, theta):
    AF_out = 1
    self.cur = np.array(cur,int)

    for m in range(int(RING_NUM)):
        for i in range(RING_ELEMENT_NUM[m], int(np.sum(np.fromiter((RING_ELEMENT_NUM[0:m]), int)))):
            AF_out = 1 + np.sum(self.cur[i] * np.real(exp(1j * K * (m * WAVELENGTH / 2) *
                                                           np.sin(theta) * np.cos(PHI - 2 * np.pi * (i - 1) / RING_ELEMENT_NUM[m]))))
    return AF_out
```